# Gatling: Handle RequestTimeoutException

Tags: gatling

How can one handle RequestTimeoutException in Gatling so a scenario doesn't get marked as failed?

I have looked into https://github.com/gatling/gatling/blob/master/gatling-core/src/main/resources/gatling-defaults.conf but couldn't find a corresponding parameter.

Answer (score 1):

You can change timeout in `gatling.conf` of your project, but I don't think you can make Gatling completely ignore it. I wonder what is the reason behind this goal, cause catching failures and put it in report is smth you are looking for?

If you have chained requests and with timeout the following requests are useless, you can use `exitBlockOnFail` to stop on failed (time outed)request.

Answer (score 0):

```
http {
    #fetchedCssCacheMaxCapacity = 200          # Cache size for CSS parsed content, set to 0 to disable
    #fetchedHtmlCacheMaxCapacity = 200         # Cache size for HTML parsed content, set to 0 to disable
    #perUserCacheMaxCapacity = 200             # Per virtual user cache size, set to 0 to disable
    #warmUpUrl = "https://gatling.io"          # The URL to use to warm-up the HTTP stack (blank means disabled)
    #enableGA = true                           # Very light Google Analytics (Gatling and Java version), please support
    #pooledConnectionIdleTimeout = 60000       # Timeout in millis for a connection to stay idle in the pool
    requestTimeout = 120000                    # Timeout in millis for performing an HTTP request
    #enableHostnameVerification = false        # When set to true, enable hostname verification: SSLEngine.setHttpsEndpointIdentificationAlgorithm("HTTPS")
    dns {
      #queryTimeout = 5000                     # Timeout in millis of each DNS query in millis
      #maxQueriesPerResolve = 6                # Maximum allowed number of DNS queries for a given name resolution
    }
```

This is it: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SaZIq.png

You can tweak it as much as you want.